How to update a field in React Hook Form based on other fields' values?
I'm using React Hook Form with three input fields:

Start date
End date
The number of nights (calculated from the two dates).

I want the night difference to update automatically whenever the start or end date changes.
Is there a way to update the night difference without using onChange, but by placing the logic inside register?
Codesandbox
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, getValues, setValue } = useForm();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <label>Start Date</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          id="startDate"
          {...register("startDate", {
            required: "This field is required",
          })}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setValue(
              "numNights",
              Math.floor(
                (new Date(getValues().endDate) - new Date(e.target.value)) /
                  (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
              ) || ""
            )
          }
        />

        <label>End Date</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          id="endDate"
          {...register("endDate", {
            required: "This field is required",
            validate: (value) => {
              if (value <= getValues().startDate) {
                return "End date must be after the start date";
              }
            },
          })}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setValue(
              "numNights",
              Math.floor(
                (new Date(e.target.value) - new Date(getValues().startDate)) /
                  (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
              )
            )
          }
        />

        <label>Nights</label>
        <input type="text" id="numNights" readOnly {...register("numNights")} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}


You can use useWatch hook from react hook form to monitor the value of your input and use setValue from the same in useEffect.

You can use useWatch to observe changes in the date fields.
By using useEffect, you can then calculate the difference in days (nights) whenever either the start or end date is changed.
Simplified solution:

Watch the startDate and endDate fields
Calculate the difference in days (nights) between the two dates
Update the "Nights" field automatically with setValue in a useEffect hook

Codesandbox Demo
import { useForm, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const { register, getValues, setValue, control } = useForm();

  const startDate = useWatch({ control, name: "startDate" });
  const endDate = useWatch({ control, name: "endDate" });

  const calculateNights = (start, end) => {
    if (start && end) {
      const diffDays = Math.floor(
        (new Date(end) - new Date(start)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
      );
      return diffDays > 0 ? diffDays : "";
    }
    return "";
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue("numNights", calculateNights(startDate, endDate));
  }, [startDate, endDate, setValue]);

  return (
    <form>
      <label>Start Date</label>
      <input type="date" {...register("startDate", { required: true })} />

      <label>End Date</label>
      <input type="date" {...register("endDate", { required: true })} />

      <label>Nights</label>
      <input type="text" readOnly {...register("numNights")} />
    </form>
  );
}


Thank you for your help! Earlier, I was trying to use both useWatch() and useEffect() but couldn't get them to work together correctly. Your solution made everything click for me. I appreciate your clear explanation and for showing me how to properly use these two hooks together.
